# Regex to detect semi-colon in strings

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a string to detect semicolons from. Only those semicolons which are not inside HTML tags should be matched.

The best regex I have come up with is:

```
/(^|>)[^<>]*?;[^<>]*?(<|$)/
```

The above regex I provided works well if I want to detect `;` between HTML tags `<>` and the values are on separate lines, like this:

```
Value1;
<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value2</p>;
<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value3;</p>;
Value4
```

However, it fails if everything is on a single line, like:

```
Value1;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value2</p>;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value3</p>;Value4
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried your regex against the single line version using JavaScript, and it worked fine (as long as I specified the `g` global search flag). What language/platform are you using, and how exactly is it failing?

Comment: I doubt! My requirement is basically to replace every `;` outside HTML Tags `<>` with a `\n`.

`if(this.value.match((/(^|>)[^<>]*?;[^<>]*?(<|$)/g))) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/;/g, ';');
      }
      else {this.value = this.value.replace(/;/g, '\n');}`

The if condition doesn't seem to work well. @David784

Comment: Try this: `;(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)` [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BBhGd4/1)

Comment: @MaciejLos Your regex works well with the demo you shared, but still not matching properly with my code.

My requirement is basically to replace every `;` outside HTML Tags `<>` with a `\n`. `if(this.value.match((/(^|>)[^<>]*?;[^<>]*?(<|$)/g))) {
this.value = this.value.replace(/;/g, ';');       
}else {this.value = this.value.replace(/;/g, '\n');}` 

The if condition doesn't seem to work well. Am I missing something? Assuming it to be a silly mistake

Comment: In the code you posted, you're using wrong regex pattern.

Comment: Oh my bad. I didn't update the comment. In my code I am using the one you suggested.

`if(this.value.match((/;(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)/gm))) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/;/g, ';');
      }
      else {this.value = this.value.replace(/;/g, '\n');}`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is more with the code implementation than with the RegExp. A few minor modifications to the capturing groups, but that's it.

The problem is an if loop like that won't really work. You just need to use a single `.replace`. Try this:

```js
const value = 'Value1;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value2</p>;<p style="color:red; font-weight:400;">Value3</p>;Value4';

const newVal = value.replace(/((?:^|>)[^<>]*);([^<>]*(?:<|$))/g, '$1\n$2');
console.log(newVal);
```

Here are the mods I made to the RegExp:

- make the "or" conditions non-capturing groups `(?:)`
- make capturing groups for the parts before/after the semicolon
- remove unneeded `?`: `*` means zero or more...so you don't need it. (You could have it, but it's not needed).

Comment: This looks good but the data is input given by the user. So the value string will change.

For ex: If I give just -

`M1`\
`M2`\
`M3`

It outputs as 

`M1;M2`\
`M3`

Consider \ as a new line.